# Conditional custom output around products sale price and regular price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I'm trying to work on a custom conditional output where when a product loop is found with sales price, it adds a class to the sale price tag. If there's only regular price, it adds this class to regular price tag.

I can't seem to get this to work after looking on & off from different documentations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ){
    ob_start();
        global $product; 
        if (isset($product->sale_price)) {
            return str_replace( '</del>', '<span class="amount">text</span></del>', $price );
            return str_replace( '</ins>', '<span class="highlight amount">highlight here</span></del>', $price );
        }
        else {
            return str_replace( '</ins>', '<span class="highlight amount">highlight here</span>text</del>', $price );
        }
}
```

I'm using the regular price filter & trying to change the span class="amount" tag to ins span class="amount", however I still get the same output. 
Any idea?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'price_custom_class', 10, 2 );
function price_custom_class( $price, $product ){ 
    return str_replace( '<span class="amount"></span>', '<ins><span class="amount">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price    ).'</span></ins>', $price );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hook is a filter with 2 variables (`$price` and `$instance`) and you `return $price` instead of `echo $price`). You could try to use it this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html','price_custom_class', 10, 2 ); 
function price_custom_class( $price, $product ){ 
    if (isset($product->sale_price)) {
        $price = '<del class="strike">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).'</del> 
        <ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->sale_price ).'</ins>';
    }
    else
    {
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

This hook is for sale price normally.

Reference: [woocommerce_sale_price_html](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_sale_price_html/)

For regular price, you have `woocommerce_price_html` filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'price_custom_class', 10, 2 );
function price_custom_class( $price, $product ){ 
    // your code
    return $price;
}
```

Reference: [woocommerce_price_html](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_price_html/)

Answer (score 1):

You need filter hook here, not action hook, to hook a function or method to a specific filter action.
 change to

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html','price_custom_class');
```

Comment: yes i figure out a filter hook would be the right way 5 mins after i go thru it. Looking that i would be replacing both sale_price & regular_price, would  the get_price_html works better for this?

Comment: Yes, it will show the replaced value when you call using get_price_html function