# Display Woocommerce Sale Badge with Percentage Saved

Tags: woocommerce, percentage, badge

I'm trying to display the discount amount as a percentage in the Woocommerce Sale Badge, I found the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'wc_custom_replace_sale_text' );
function wc_custom_replace_sale_text( $html ) {
global $product;
$percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product-
>get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100 );
return str_replace( __( 'Sale!', 'woocommerce' ), __( '', 'woocommerce' 
).$percentage.'% OFF', $html ); }
```

But get this warning on variable products:
Warning: Division by zero in /functions.php on line etc... pointing at this line

```
  $percentage = round( ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100 );
```

Any suggestions how I can get this to work would be very much appreciated!

Kind regards,
JP

Comment: You can probably find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230027/adding-the-discount-percentage-to-variable-products-on-sale . I believe that you are only returning simple product prices as it is right now, and need some more arguments to return variations

Comment: Another option is Also this http://www.wpstuffs.com/display-product-discountoffer-percentage-bubble-woocommerce/ - however consider this Change https://www.tmdhosting.com/kb/question/how-to-show-woocommerce-discount-in-percentage/

Comment: Hi Chri.s, thanks for the help buddy, all sorted :)